# Loop through json object and sort in order

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Currently I have a small piece of code which loops through a json object:

```
for (var key in json_object) {
    if (json_object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var value       = key; //e.g. 50_100, 1000_2000, 20_50 etc
    }
}
```

I'm going to be outputting these values into a list later on. But the problem is that these values aren't in any order right now.

I'd like to be able to have these values sorted out in order. So my question is, is this possible and if so how?

Thanks!

Comment: Object keys don't have an order. If defined at compile time, order of keys is retained, else sorted by alphabetical order of keyname

Comment: You can make array of these key values and than sort it. As #gurvinder372 said - no sort for keys in object

Comment: My purpose is to be able to output them in an ordered list later on, so is there any alternative or other ways to achieve what I need?

Comment: @S.Nadezhnyy do you mean I save these values into an array and then sort that array?

Comment: @user2028856: You could serve an array (list) in the JSON that has the right order up front.

Comment: @user2028856 that's right. See Asaf David 's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript, object properties are not guaranteed a specific order, so if you want to maintain order, you would likely need to write the object properties into an array of objects.

That could look like this:

```
var object_array = [];
// map properties into array of objects
for (var key in json_object) {
    if (json_object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        object_array.push({
            'key': key;
            'value': value;
        });   
    }
}
// sort array of objects
object_array.sort(function(a,b) {
    // note that you might need to change the sort comparison function to meet your needs
    return (a.value > b.value);
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't seem to perform any sorting for strings such as this "100_500" , "800_1000", "2000_3000" etc

Comment: @user2028856 That is why I indicated that you might need to change the sort comparison to do something applicable to the values you are sorting by.  In the case of your strings, how would you propose to perform the sort?

Comment: Your comparison function is invalid, see [Sorting in JavaScript: Shouldn't returning a boolean be enough for a comparison function?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24080785/1048572)

Answer (score 1):

After reading all solutions, I realized my solution was wrong. Object.keys is good for getting an array of keys only, so Mike Brant's solution is correct, although a little fix is needed since `value` is not a variable there. Finally here's a fixed solution based on his solution + the requested sorting from the comments:

```
var arr = [];

for (var key in json_object) {
    if (json_object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        arr.push({
            'key': key;
            'value': json_object[key];
        });   
    }
}

// this will sort by the first part of the string
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.key.split('_')[0] - b.key.split('_')[0];  
}
```

Hope this helps... :-)

Comment: What is `value`? Probably not an array index.

Comment: Can you please tell me what should I use for 'value'?

Comment: You can directly use `Object.keys(obj).sort(function(){})`

Comment: @user2028856 Fixed and also added another option following Rajesh's comment

Comment: Does this method provide sorting for strings like this:  "100_500" , "800_1000", "2000_3000" etc?

Comment: It does sort, but probably not as you want it. If it compares two strings it will sort them as strings and not as number, you need to modify your values. How do you need them sorted exactly?

Comment: I'd like them sorted like this: "0_20", "20_50", "50_100", "100_300", "300_500", "500_1000", "1000_2000", "2000_3000", "3000_4000"

Comment: Right now they're like this: "100_300", "500_1000", "300_500", "1000_2000", "50_100", "20_50", "2000_3000", "3000_4000", "0_20"

Comment: That filter makes no sense, `Object.keys` already returns only own properties.

Comment: Following all your comments, i've completely changed my answer + added the requested sorting. If you need to sort by the second part as well just let me know

Answer (score 0):

The following fixes `eslint` issues I found in the other solutions:

```
var arr = [];
Object.keys(json_object).forEach(function(key) {
  arr.push({
    'key': key,
    'value': json_object[key]
  });  
})
```